# g++ not finding library in /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, ld, glog

I'm trying to get g++ to find `glog` on its own (OS X 10.11.5). I installed glog (tried with both cmake from a github pull as well as brew install - same result in both cases). Then I tried to compile this file:

```
#include <glog/logging.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int* x = nullptr;
  CHECK_NOTNULL(x);
  return 0;
}
```

by running `g++ -lglog -I/usr/local/include test.cpp`

This fails with the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lglog
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, when I compile with `g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lglog -I/usr/local/include test.cpp` it works fine.

I tried adding `/usr/local/lib` into my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to no avail.

Normally, I wouldn't mind, but I'm using CMake (which finds glog just fine), and I don't want to "hardcode" library paths in there so that it's portable. I tried this before on another Mac and it worked fine, so I'm not sure what's going on. Any advice on fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a potential solution:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Not sure if this is the *best* solution but it works for now. I can put this locally in my .bashrc.

**UPDATE:** On macOS if you run `xcode-select --install` it should fix these issues.